# How to set Div with 100% height with border?

Tags: html, css

I want to divide page into two "div"s. Left(25%) and right(75%). And i wanted a border between the two, to separate them. But unless I enter text/image into the "div"s they don't expand.

```
<div>
    <div class="left">
        <img src="granted_300_50.png" id="logo">
    </div>  
</div>
```

And the css is:

```
div.left{
    background-image: url("flower_ornament2_watermark.png") ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color:white;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-right: 2px solid #c3c3c3; 
    border-left: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 100%;
    width: 350px;
    margin: 0px;
    outline: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Help?

Digvijay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `height` in percentage on inline elements works only if the **container** has a specific height set too, up to the `body` and `html`.

This CSS should work:

```
html,body { height:100% ;}
div#container { height:100%; }
div.left { height:100%; }
```

---

Another common workaround is the so called "faux column" method:

- http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/
- http://woorkup.com/2009/10/11/really-simple-css-trick-for-equal-height-columns/

---

You can also use `display:table;` for the container and `display:table-cell;` for the floated divs. But it's not supported by IE7.

```
div#container { display:table; }
div.left { display:table-cell; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

**CSS**

```
.left{
    width:25%;
    height:100px;
    border-right:1px solid #ccc;
}

.right{
    width:75%;
    height:100px;
    border-left:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you also set a height on the `body` and `html` nodes, they will collapse. You can fix this by setting them to 100% height:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/Nhajy/

CSS:

```
html, body, div { height: 100%; }

div.left {
    background-image: url("flower_ornament2_watermark.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-right: 2px solid #c3c3c3; 
    border-left: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 100%;
    width: 350px;
    margin: 0px;
    outline: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}​
```

The other solution is to set a `min-height`:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/MSLdT/

CSS:

```
div.left {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-right: 2px solid #c3c3c3; 
    border-left: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-height: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 350px;
    margin: 0px;
    outline: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}​
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use something like:

/*css code*/

```
height:calc(100%-2px);
border:1px solid black;
```